# Spring Security Oauth2 removeAccessToken is not working

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a scenario where once after logout I want to invalidate the access token generated for that session.
I'm revoking access token using TokenStore on logout. I am not getting any error. but after successful revocation also I am able use the old access token to access my application. Here is my code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/revoke-token", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    try {
    if (authHeader != null) {
        String tokenValue = authHeader.replace("Bearer", "").trim();
        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
        tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);
         
    }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Done";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of removing or revoking a JWT. It has to expire by itself